# downloading the content of a file described in an entry

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I'm building a webapp in python, using Oauth 2.0 with multiscope token. Accessing and processing document list feeds works fine.

But when I try to download the content of files those were not converted to a Google Documents format I always get HTTP 401 error as response. It doesn't change anything if I append the token at the end of the request url or not. I send GET to the address that I found in the src attribute of the entry's content tag. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Or what is the point of *docs.googleusercontent.com* token scope if it is not possible to get access with token?

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to use the new Google Drive API if you can. To download a file from Drive, you have to send an authorized GET request to the file's downloadUrl, as explained in the reference guide:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

The Google Drive SDK also has extensive documentation about the authorization process (https://developers.google.com/drive/about-auth) and a complete Python sample running on App Engine:

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python